# Server Error in '/' Application (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-web-developer

I just setup up member ship roles and registration on my website with visual web developer using the tutorial on msdn. It works perfectly locally, but when i uploaded it to my server, I get the following page:

```
"Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]


Source File: machine.config    Line: 160 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4200; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4016 "
```

Does anybody know why I'm seeing this and how I may go about fixinf this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Bael.

**EDIT:**

I have just looked at my web.config file after reading the following line in the error message: "The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty." ... And have noticed that the following element is completely empty:

`<connectionStrings/>` // Is this one supposed to be empty? if not what should go here? In the error it implies it shouldn't be empty. Also, I don't know where I should place LocalSqlServer

**LATEST EDIT**

After changing DataSource to LocalHost i get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/JTS' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4849015
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection owningObject) +4862333
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +342
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +221
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +189
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +31
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +433
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +499
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +65
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) +87
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +221
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) +815
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +105
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved) +42
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +78
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +60
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +119
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +101
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +166
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927
```

Comment: Are you using a role provider?

Comment: yeah i am using a role provider :)

Comment: Do you have SQL Server installed?

Comment: Do you actually have an instance of SQL Server running on the server (or on some other machine it can reach)?  You need that in order to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocalSqlServer is a default connection string entry in machine.config. It is always present although not in the app/web config file.

It points to your local instance of sqlexpress that was installed with visual studio.

By default the membership provider, upon configuration, creates a local .mdf file in your app_data folder (click show all files). This database has been provisioned.

If for some reason you want to use a different database you must provision it with aspnet_regsql.exe . You will find it in your windows/microsoft.net/framework/2.0.xxxx directory.

from the commandline run aspnet_regsql.exe /? to get instructions.

So.. this may be why you are getting these errors. If you DO want to use a different database and do not want to edit the membership section to point to the new db you must remove localSqlServer and then re-add

OR, again, configure your membership element to point to a different connection.

**EITHER WAY you need a PROVISIONED database other than the local user instance that was provisioned by VS that you are using during development and a connection string that points to it.**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <remove name='LocalSqlServer' />
  <add name='LocalSqlServer' connectionString='Data Source=DBServerName;
    Integrated Security=false;Initial Catalog=DBName;
    User ID=DBLogin;Password=DBPassword' providerName='System.Data.SqlClient' />
</connectionStrings>
```

EDIT: reread your question:

The problem is that the host does not have sql or does not allow user instances. Typically in a hosted site, you will request a database and upon getting the credentials, use aspnet_regsql.exe to provision that database. In this case you MUST modify the membership section in web.config to point to your new database.

hth

Comment: By default LocalSqlServer is defined in the machine.config, however many hosts will remove that entry.

Comment: yes, you are right ben.

@BAEL - I have answered you question with the resolution to your exception.

Answer (score 9):

Ensure you have connection string named `LocalSqlServer` added [connectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx) element of your `Web.config`.

If you're using standard ASP.NET Membership/Role providers, by default they are declared as this:

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <add
      name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, ..."
      connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" ...
```

It's the `connectionStringName` which is likely to be causing this error. If you plan on using Membership/Role API, you'll have to either *add* a connection string named `LocalSqlServer` to `<connectionString>` secion of your `Web.config`, or change `connectionStringAttribute` so that its value will be a valid (and existing) connection string name.

Comment: For some more information on this see https://support.discountasp.net/KB/a337/how-to-configure-aspnet-20-membershiproles-provider.aspx

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't comletely understand. what am i supposed to add to the connectionsString element?

Comment: @bastijn, i follwed the instructions on that site and in msdos it said something about a network-related or instance-specific error occured. the error's even bigger now that i've changed it...

Comment: The amount of error text does say nothing about the error itself, remember that forever :).

Comment: thanks i'll make sure to remember that! :D ..it sure can seem a little scary though lol

Answer (score 3):

If you have .Net membership roles provider see [this](https://support.discountasp.net/KB/a337/how-to-configure-aspnet-20-membershiproles-provider.aspx) link first.

**Some explanation since you said you did not understand**

Net membership roles provider is setup to look for 'LocalSQLServer'. This means that we have to supply the details for a connection named LocalSQLServer or say it isnt needed. What you can do is in you web.config file find the `<connectionstrings>` part and add a line:

```
<add name='LocalSqlServer' connectionString='Data Source=DBServerName;
Integrated Security=false;Initial Catalog=DBName;
User ID=DBLogin;Password=DBPassword' providerName='System.Data.SqlClient' />
```

Replace the DBServerName with your SQL db server addon, DBName with the database name that came with your addon, DBLogin and Password should be replaced with what came with your SQL addon.

If you don't want to use LocalSQLSever you can remove it by

```
 <remove name='LocalSqlServer' />
```

in your web.config file under the  properties. Then change the connection string name on your roles provider to the connection string name you will be using. So change your exisiting connection string to name='LocalSQLServer'.

Comment: thanks for that. it still doesnt work. I'm not sure what you mean about the "addon"?

Comment: Data Source=localhost for instance if you run your site on the machine where your DB is on. I think username and pw can be left out if you use standard windows login.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've updated my question with stack-trace information.

Comment: Have a look down here since it seems to explain alot about what you are doing. http://odetocode.com/articles/428.aspx. Also have a look at part one. They explain about LocalSQLServer. I'm afraid, since im not completely familiar with asp.net 2.0 I cannot help you any further.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I really do appreciate your time and effort. :)

Comment: By the way, the error you get is because of wrong information in you connect string line, it cannot connect to your DB. Probably because you are using the standard DB which is not localhost. The information in the link above should give the correct connectionstring to use for the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

[Enable Named Pipes and TCP/IP for Microsoft SQL Server](http://download.pro.parallels.com/10.3.1/docs/windows/Guides/pcpw_upgrade_guide/7351.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you're getting a connection string from the machine.config.
The easiest way to get rid of these, rather than using remove is to use a self closed clear element in the connectionstrings section.

The out of the box membership provider should have had a local connection string entry (new projects get this by default). You could create a new project and swipe it from there.

On the server you'll need to check SQL is installed correctly, and to update the connection string to match the server details.

Answer (score 0):

I've often seen this message when the ASPNET user does not have read access to the config directory for the framework in question. It looks to me like you have a file directive in one of your keys, and the framework does not have access (either through permissions or because the file is not there) to read it.